# implementing GCMathParser on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks

i am trying to use the GCMathParser for an iphone application and i cannot find any support on implementing this framework. people keep saying its easy and im kinda confused, any help would be great thanks!

Comment: You need to give more information. Are you interested in adding frameworks to a project in general or is there something specific about GCMathParser that is confusing?

Comment: well i downloaded the source file for it from apptree(i think thats it) and tried tieing the conversion parts of it into my app (just removing the view controller from the sample code) but it keeps generating numerous errors and everytime i fix one i get tons more.

Comment: what errors are you getting?  Please provide more information than "this isn't working. kthxbai".

Comment: /Users/shane/Documents/Function Calculator/parser/GCMathParser.h:9:24: error: Cocoa/Cocoa.h: No such file or directory

tried adding the framework again and still the same error, from what i know the iphone doesnt utilize the cocoa framework but instead the cocoa touch framework, not too sure, there is just NO documentation ANYWHERE on implementing this for the iphone, just a lot of: "use this"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two changes you need to make in order to use this:

1. Change `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` to `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` (You could probably get away with using `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`, too)
2. Try to compile again.  You'll get errors about an unknown symbol "pi".  Change the three occurrences of those to `M_PI` (the constant defined in `<math.h>` for π).

You'll still get warnings (about deprecated methods), but it will compile and work.

Comment: worked perfectly thank you! im just not too accustomed with os x programming vs iphone programming i guess haha

Comment: If you have any additional questions, Graham Cox, the author of GCMathParser, is very responsive.

Answer (score 2):

If you have UI classes, then you will need to remove them (as you noted you have). If you have non-UI classes importing Cocoa.h, they generally shouldn't be (AppKit, which is implemented in Cocoa.h, is mostly UI). Replace Cocoa.h with `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`. If they actually rely on things in Cocoa.h, then you have porting work to do.