# Use GCMathParser in iOS application? Xcode. 

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm a noob, so basically, HOW DO I PUT IT IN MY APP? :D

I am wondering how you would use a Parser in an iOS application.
I'm quite a noob so all the help I can get on this topic would be great.
In the end I would like to be able to convert a mathematical string into a answer.

Right now this is what I am using:

```
        answer = [[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:typeTo.text, nil] expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
        typeTo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", answer];
        answerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ANS { %@ }", answer];
```

But I heard that using the parsers is a better way of doing this.

This is the file I would like to use in my iOS project: http://apptree.net/parser.htm

Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: Found the solution.

Quite easy.

Just drag and drop the files given with CGMathParser into your project folder, and then change some things like this question states: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505695/implementing-gcmathparser-on-iphone
Then your good to go!

Hope this helps some other people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Quite easy.

Just drag and drop the files given with CGMathParser into your project folder, and then change some things like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505695/implementing-gcmathparser-on-iphone) states. Then your good to go!

Hope this helps some other people!